# How do I use conditional formatting in google sheets to highlight the name for the 1st, 2nd, 3rd place highest sales?

Tags: google-sheets

[**Click Here**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nvOvJqpvIoyHXS5un_7JQrdignjNtwriKDwl2IQSuAs/edit?usp=sharing)

I want to highlight the name of the people (overall), not for each team: 1st place (gold), 2nd place (silver), 3rd place (bronze) colors in the order/place they came in without changing the cell structure or format to the spreadsheet.

I've tried to use conditional formatting, but I get lost with knowing how to represent a different cell.

Answer (score 0):

Create the following conditional formatting rules:

**Apply to range**

```
A2:A5,A8:A11,E8:E11,E2:E5
```

**Custom formula is**

```cpp
=D2=LARGE({$D$2:$D$5,$H$2:$H$5,$D$8:$D$11,$H$8:$H$11},1) // 1st place
=D2=LARGE({$D$2:$D$5,$H$2:$H$5,$D$8:$D$11,$H$8:$H$11},2) // 2nd place
=D2=LARGE({$D$2:$D$5,$H$2:$H$5,$D$8:$D$11,$H$8:$H$11},3) // 3rd place
```